# Does FirebaseMessagingService survives device reboot?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I am new to Firebase and I want to implement FCM to send notifications from Firebase console. I created `FirebaseMessagingService` in my app, my only question is does `FirebaseMessagingService` survives device reboot? What if the device is rebooted and then a notification message comes from cloud?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The firebase services get started automatically after a successful reboot and if in case the device is not online the notification remains pending for at least 4 weeks, and when the device is again online, then all the pending notifications are delivered.

Please have a look at this documentation
[Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options)

Comment: thank you so much for your help. My doubt is clear now.

Comment: I think you can accept answer but cant vote it if you have points below 15.. try to click gray right button below two arrows

Answer (score 1):

Firebase data messages do survive and don't need the device to be on and the app running in the foreground or background to be able to deliver. Just set the **priority** parameter to high

Comment: Actually it does survive if the device is turned off or is out of network. You need to set the **time to live** parameter. For more information [read the documentation here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#ttl)

Comment: @ChetanAshtivkar you are right. But I figured it out by setting the **priority** to high. Would edit my answer now